# How do I use sumifs for a data set that has duplicates?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The raw data looks something like this:
[image]

My goal here is to extract each client's sales sorted by Desc Code, so the output would be something like this:

[image]

I feel `sumifs` is a good function to use. However, there are duplicates in the data such as the Desc Codes and the Client names. I was wondering if there's a way to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Another problem is that `Client 1` and `EPG`, or `Client 1` and `DIST`, don't appear on the same row in the raw data.

Comment: Yes, that's right. And there are thousands of clients in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the data looks like the one above, I'd do the following.

I'd create a helper column E to fill the client name in each row:

```
=+IF(A2="",E1,A2)
```

So, the column E have all the rows with the proper client. And then do the sum:

```
=+SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,"EPG",E:E,"Client 1")
```

You can replace "EPG" and "Client 1" for the referenced cell.

As "Des Code" only have data on the subtotal lines, the formula should sum the amounts only one time each (subtotals).